# spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server vs spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 which to use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, dependencies

i just getting started to learning Spring Security with OAuth2 and i want to create Authorization Server and Resource Server for my microservice Restful Api. But i am confuse which dependency to start with, since i found some of them. i use spring boot 2.4.1 version. here i list it below :

This one i found it at spring initializer page, when i try to add OAuth2 library, is this one the latest version?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

below this one i found it at some tutorial, which is i think this one is already deprecated right?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And last one, is this one below, since i don't see there is an updated version anymore, is this one deprecated too?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

which one should i use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.4.x [uses](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) Spring Security 5.4.x, which sadly removed its support for authorization servers.

There's a new project, [spring-authorization-sever](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server), aimed at bringing it back in the future, but currently it's only at version 0.0.3.

If you need it for your project, I'd recommend using spring boot 2.3.x instead.

Comment: So no authorization and resource server at Spring Boot 2.4.x with Spring Security 5.4.x?

Comment: It supports resource servers, but not authorization servers. Here's the migration guide for Spring Security 5.2 (note the first paragraph) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide. More info here https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update

Comment: Take a look at this link, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix

Answer (score 0):

As @dislexit commented the authorization server was removed from spring security and there is another project that will support it, coming to the answer Spring Security 5+ will support the resource and client features of oauth2 so you can use it instead of both you mentioned.

follow this link to see the differences https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix